# Can USB bandwidth be asymmetrical

Tags: usb

Does a 5 Gbps flash drive communicate at 2.5 Gbps maximum in both directions or can one direction use part of the other direction's bandwidth?

I know encoding, flow control, good controllers, etc influence speeds and that advertised speeds are theoretical at best.

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 is full duplex compared to USB 2.0 half duplex, so (theoretically) it can transfer data at 5 Gbps on both directions AT THE SAME TIME.

Comment: USB3 can transfer this at the same time, but the endpoins (flash memory) can't do this simultaneously. This makes the difference.